# Error with Homebrew install of ffmpeg --with all options

Tags: install, homebrew

After installing ffmpeg using Homebrew on my late 2012 MacBook Air i7 with macOS 10.12.3, I get this message:

`Error: File exists - /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/.brew`

This path is a link to `/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.2/.brew` which `ls -al` reveals to contain only the Ruby file, "ffmpeg.rb"

Prior to this I'd installed ffmpeg successfully using `brew install ffmpeg` but then uninstalled it to re-install with all the options per `brew options ffmpeg`:

`brew install ffmpeg --with-chromaprint --with-fdk-aac --with-fontconfig --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-game-music-emu --with-libass --with-libbluray --with-libbs2b --with-libcaca --with-libebur128 --with-libgsm --with-libmodplug --with-libsoxr --with-libssh --with-libvidstab --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openh264 --with-openjpeg --with-openssl --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-rubberband --with-schroedinger --with-sdl2 --with-snappy --with-speex --with-tesseract --with-theora --with-tools --with-two-lame --with-wavpack --with-webp --with-x265 --with-xz --with-zeromq --with-zimg`

Now instead of a successful installation end message I get this:

```
...
==> make install
==> make alltools
Error: File exists - /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/.brew
```

With `brew uninstall ffmpeg` I've deleted the `/usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/` linked directory and the actual `/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/` directory. I tried the install again but I get the same error. Of note, it appears that ffmpeg is successfully installed:

```
$  ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-chromaprint --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libebur128 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-librubberband --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-opencl --enable-openssl --enable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.1.2/include/openjpeg-2.1 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
```

Of note, I have used `brew prune`, `brew update`, `brew upgrade`, `brew cleanup`, `brew doctor` and

```
$  brew -v
Homebrew 1.1.8
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 35fb; last commit 2017-01-29)
```

Also of note, considering the error message comes while the install is in the `==> make alltools` phase, I notice in the `/usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/.brew/ffmpeg.rb` file the following code:

```
class Ffmpeg < Formula
...
  def install
...
    if build.with? "tools"
      system "make", "alltools"
      bin.install Dir["tools/*"].select { |f| File.executable? f }
    end
  end
...
end
```

I am not sure if this is related but since I am using thw `--with-tools` option, perhaps the `bin.install` is raising the error?

Even with the error message, the resulting install has ffmpeg, ffprobe, ffserver but `ffplay` is not recognized as a command...

The INSTALL_RECEIPT.json file indicates that none of the options are being used:

```
{"homebrew_version":null,"used_options":[],"unused_options":["--with-fdk-aac","--with-libass","--with-libebur128","--with-libsoxr","--with-libssh","--with-tesseract","--with-libvidstab","--with-opencore-amr","--with-openh264","--with-openjpeg","--with-openssl","--with-rtmpdump","--with-rubberband","--with-schroedinger","--with-sdl2","--with-snappy","--with-tools","--with-webp","--with-x265","--with-xz","--with-zeromq","--with-zimg","--without-lame","--without-qtkit","--without-securetransport","--without-x264","--without-xvid","--with-fontconfig","--with-freetype","--with-frei0r","--with-game-music-emu","--with-libbluray","--with-libbs2b","--with-libcaca","--with-libgsm","--with-libmodplug","--with-libvorbis","--with-libvpx","--with-opus","--with-speex","--with-theora","--with-two-lame","--with-wavpack"],"built_as_bottle":true,"poured_from_bottle":true,"installed_as_dependency":true,"installed_on_request":false,"changed_files":["INSTALL_RECEIPT.json","lib/pkgconfig/libavcodec.pc","lib/pkgconfig/libavdevice.pc","lib/pkgconfig/libavfilter.pc","lib/pkgconfig/libavformat.pc","lib/pkgconfig/libavresample.pc","lib/pkgconfig/libavutil.pc","lib/pkgconfig/libpostproc.pc","lib/pkgconfig/libswresample.pc","lib/pkgconfig/libswscale.pc","share/man/man1/ffmpeg-all.1","share/man/man1/ffmpeg-filters.1","share/man/man1/ffprobe-all.1","share/man/man1/ffserver-all.1","share/man/man1/ffserver.1"],"time":1485728076,"source_modified_time":1480980538,"HEAD":null,"stdlib":null,"compiler":"clang","runtime_dependencies":null,"source":{"path":"/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/ffmpeg.rb","tap":"homebrew/core","spec":"stable","versions":{"stable":"3.2.2","devel":null,"head":"HEAD","version_scheme":0}}}
(extra line for ease of scroll viewing)
```

Why is this error message getting reported and what do I need to do for a successful install with all the options?

--------------------------UPDATE
Using `$  brew install ffmpeg --force --with...` all the above options I still get the same error, but, using:

```
$  brew unlink ffmpeg && brew link ffmpeg
```

I unlinked 84 symlinks and then linked 114 (an additional 30 not linked with the install). With that I now at least have ffplay and the INSTALL_RECEIPT.json file has stuff in the "used" section:

```
{"homebrew_version":"1.1.8","used_options":["--with-chromaprint","--with-fdk-aac","--with-fontconfig","--with-freetype","--with-frei0r","--with-game-music-emu","--with-libass","--with-libbluray","--with-libbs2b","--with-libcaca","--with-libebur128","--with-libgsm","--with-libmodplug","--with-libsoxr","--with-libssh","--with-libvidstab","--with-libvorbis","--with-libvpx","--with-opencore-amr","--with-openh264","--with-openjpeg","--with-openssl","--with-opus","--with-rtmpdump","--with-rubberband","--with-schroedinger","--with-sdl2","--with-snappy","--with-speex","--with-tesseract","--with-theora","--with-tools","--with-two-lame","--with-wavpack","--with-webp","--with-x265","--with-xz","--with-zeromq","--with-zimg"],"unused_options":["--without-lame","--without-qtkit","--without-securetransport","--without-x264","--without-xvid"],"built_as_bottle":false,"poured_from_bottle":false,"installed_as_dependency":false,"installed_on_request":true,"changed_files":null,"time":1485730992,"source_modified_time":1480980538,"HEAD":"e59ada508727f11464595893783beb914c26f60b","stdlib":"libcxx","compiler":"clang","runtime_dependencies":[{"full_name":"lame","version":"3.99.5"},{"full_name":"x264","version":"r2748"},{"full_name":"xvid","version":"1.3.4"},{"full_name":"chromaprint","version":"1.3"},{"full_name":"fdk-aac","version":"0.1.5"},{"full_name":"libpng","version":"1.6.28"},{"full_name":"freetype","version":"2.7.1"},{"full_name":"fontconfig","version":"2.12.1"},{"full_name":"frei0r","version":"1.4"},{"full_name":"game-music-emu","version":"0.6.1"},{"full_name":"gettext","version":"0.19.8.1"},{"full_name":"libffi","version":"3.0.13"},{"full_name":"pcre","version":"8.39"},{"full_name":"glib","version":"2.50.2"},{"full_name":"fribidi","version":"0.19.7"},{"full_name":"libass","version":"0.13.6"},{"full_name":"libbluray","version":"0.9.3"},{"full_name":"flac","version":"1.3.2"},{"full_name":"libogg","version":"1.3.2"},{"full_name":"libvorbis","version":"1.3.5"},{"full_name":"libsndfile","version":"1.0.26"},{"full_name":"libbs2b","version":"3.1.0"},{"full_name":"libcaca","version":"0.99b19"},{"full_name":"speex","version":"1.2.0"},{"full_name":"libebur128","version":"1.2.0"},{"full_name":"libgsm","version":"1.0.13"},{"full_name":"libmodplug","version":"0.8.8.5"},{"full_name":"libsoxr","version":"0.1.2"},{"full_name":"openssl","version":"1.0.2k"},{"full_name":"libssh","version":"0.7.3"},{"full_name":"libvidstab","version":"0.98b"},{"full_name":"libvpx","version":"1.6.1"},{"full_name":"opencore-amr","version":"0.1.4"},{"full_name":"openh264","version":"1.6.0"},{"full_name":"little-cms2","version":"2.8"},{"full_name":"jpeg","version":"8d"},{"full_name":"xz","version":"5.2.3"},{"full_name":"libtiff","version":"4.0.7"},{"full_name":"openjpeg","version":"2.1.2"},{"full_name":"opus","version":"1.1.4"},{"full_name":"rtmpdump","version":"2.4+20151223"},{"full_name":"libsamplerate","version":"0.1.9"},{"full_name":"rubberband","version":"1.8.1"},{"full_name":"orc","version":"0.4.26"},{"full_name":"schroedinger","version":"1.0.11"},{"full_name":"sdl2","version":"2.0.5"},{"full_name":"snappy","version":"1.1.4"},{"full_name":"webp","version":"0.5.2"},{"full_name":"leptonica","version":"1.74.1"},{"full_name":"tesseract","version":"3.04.01"},{"full_name":"theora","version":"1.1.1"},{"full_name":"two-lame","version":"0.3.13"},{"full_name":"wavpack","version":"5.1.0"},{"full_name":"x265","version":"2.2"},{"full_name":"zeromq","version":"4.2.1"},{"full_name":"zimg","version":"2.4"}],"source":{"path":"/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/ffmpeg.rb","tap":"homebrew/core","spec":"stable","versions":{"stable":"3.2.2","devel":null,"head":"HEAD","version_scheme":0}}}
(extra line for ease of scroll viewing)
```

I recently upgraded from macOS 10.12.2 to 10.12.3 but Homebrew appears up to date as well as `xcode-select version 2347`.

--------------------------UPDATE with pertinent --debug output

```
$  brew install ffmpeg --debug --with-chromaprint --with-fdk-aac --with-fontconfig --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-game-music-emu --with-libass --with-libbluray --with-libbs2b --with-libcaca --with-libebur128 --with-libgsm --with-libmodplug --with-libsoxr --with-libssh --with-libvidstab --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openh264 --with-openjpeg --with-openssl --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-rubberband --with-schroedinger --with-sdl2 --with-snappy --with-speex --with-tesseract --with-theora --with-tools --with-two-lame --with-wavpack --with-webp --with-x265 --with-xz --with-zeromq --with-zimg

...

==> make install
==> make alltools

...

Fixing /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/libavresample.pc permissions from 644 to 444
Fixing /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/libavutil.pc permissions from 644 to 444
Fixing /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/libpostproc.pc permissions from 644 to 444
Fixing /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/libswresample.pc permissions from 644 to 444
Fixing /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/libswscale.pc permissions from 644 to 444
Error: File exists - /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/.brew
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:297:in `mkdir'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:297:in `mkdir'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:297:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:306:in `install_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:199:in `block in install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:199:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:199:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:94:in `<main>'
$
```

Also [filed bug report to Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1933)

Comment: Have you ever downloaded or compiled the ffmpeg library without homebrew?

Comment: @NoahL nope - recently acquired used computer with a clean Lion install and then upgrade to Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per input from the [Homebrew bug report](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1933), the problem is specific to installing the [`chromaprint`](https://acoustid.org/chromaprint) option:

> The issue seems to be that `chromaprint` is being built with examples
>   by default, and therefore has a `ffmpeg` dependency. This means that
>   an installation of `ffmpeg` is already linked by the time the main
>   build actually begins.

Installing [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) with all the Homebrew options except `chromaprint` reports no errors.

Of note, installing without the `chromaprint` flag, `ffplay` works after the install without the need for using the additional command: `brew unlink ffmpeg && brew link ffmpeg`.

Also of note, installation of `ffmpeg` with the `chromaprint` option seems to prevent `ffplay` from becoming available. I am not sure what else might be compromised by this Homebrew installation bug, but otherwise, `ffmpeg` seems functional when installed with the `chromaprint` option. Even with the error message, an installation using the `--with-chromaprint` option renders the install enabled with the `chromaprint` option (per the INSTALL_RECEIPT.json file and the "enabled options" reported in the configuration) - including `fpcalc`.

[FFMPEG document on chromaprint formats](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#chromaprint-1).

Lukáš Lalinský's "[Introducing Chromaprint](https://oxygene.sk/2010/07/introducing-chromaprint/)" and "[How does Chromaprint work?](https://oxygene.sk/2011/01/how-does-chromaprint-work/)"

Comment: @LukášLalinský thank you - chromaprint is awesome and your articles are very useful!